# Change empty message multiselect primeng

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, primeng

How can I override the label 'no results found' in p-multiselect on Angular?
I'm able to change the default label, but I have not found any solution on how to override the empty message.

That's what I wrote:

```
 <p-multiSelect
                [options]="countries"
                formControlName="selectedCountries"
                [defaultLabel]="'find'"
                selectedItemsLabel="{0} items selected"
                autoWidth="false" [style]="{'width':'100%'}"
                display="chip"></p-multiSelect>
```

I found this solution:

```
.ui-multiselect-panel .ui-multiselect-empty-message {
   display: none !important;
}
```

But of course this deletes the entire div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`emptyFilterMessage="Your custom message"`

You can find it and all the other multiselect properties in PrimeNG Docs:

[image: PrimeNG docs print screen]

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/multiselect